# PHP and AJAX Log in validation

Tags: php, ajax, authentication

I need some help troubleshooting my code that's used for Log In validation.  It's a combo of AJAX and PHP.

Here's the AJAX code that's directly in the login page.

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#login_form").submit(function()
{
$("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Validating....').fadeIn(1000);
$.post("/ajax_login.php",{ user_name:$('#username').val(),password:$('#password').val()
,rand:Math.random() } ,function(data)
    {
    if (data=='no')
        {
        $("#msgbox").fadeTo
            (200,0.1,function() 
                { 
  $(this).html('Incorrect Username or  Password.')
.addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1);
                }
            );      
        }

     else if(data=='yes') 
        {
        $("#msgbox").fadeTo
            (200,0.1,function()  
                { 

$(this).html('Logging in.....').addClass('messageboxok').fadeTo
                    (900,1, function()
                        { 
                        document.location='/mainpage.php';
                        }
                    );
                }
            );
        } 

    else 
        {
        $("#msgbox").fadeTo
            (200,0.1,function()
                { 
                $(this).html('User is already logged in.').
 addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1);
                }
            );   
        }


    });
    return false; 
});
$("#password").blur(function()
{
    $("#login_form").trigger('submit');
});
});
</script>
```

PHP CODE:

```
 <? 
 //Log In credentials

 if ($rehash==$dboPW && $user_name == $dboUN  && $logged=='Y'){echo "alreadyLogged"; exit;}
 if ($rehash==$dboPW && $user_name == $dboUN  && $logged=='N')
{
echo "yes"; 
$_SESSION['login'] = $username;
$_SESSION['password'] = $rehash;
$loggedUpdate=mysql_query("UPDATE Users SET LOGGED='Y' WHERE username='$user_name'");
exit;
 }
 else
 {echo "no";}
 ?>
```

To summarize this process, someone logs in and the PHP script checks

1. if the username and password is valid AND that the person is NOT logged in already - returns value of 'yes'
2. if the username and password is valid AND that the person IS logged in already - returns value of 'alreadyLogged'
3. Invalid username or password - returns value of 'no'

This gets passed to AJAX, which SHOULD display the correct messages based on the return values from the php script. For reference (using the above summary):

1. AJAX should return: Logging in...
2. AJAX should return: User is already logged in.
3. AJAX should return: Invalid Username or Password.

The problem is this: If someone logs in correctly and IS NOT already logged in, message 2 appears instead of message 1.  (I think that message 1 may appear but it disappears so fast).

I think the culprit is AJAX but unfortunately I'm not as familiar with it as I am with PHP.

Comment: You might be sending multiple AJAX requests by mistake; I've had that issue sometimes. Can you verify that using dev tools to examine the network transmissions?

Comment: I think so too.  I ran tests on the php script and it displays the correct echo statements.  Somewhere in the AJAX script it's getting mixed up.  I'm at a loss with it.

Comment: jQuery allows you to add more than one of the same handler without warning you, so it is possible you will have multiple `submit` handlers on that `#login_form` element. What browser are you using? In Chrome dev tools you can examine an element and see what event handlers are attached to it; if there is more than one it should be easy to see there. Also, in the dev tools Network tab you can examine the individual ajax requests, which will also tell you if there is more than one. Sorry if you already know all this, but I don't know what you know, you know? :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with your php code.Your ajax code looks fine

try  this

```
if ($rehash==$dboPW && $user_name == $dboUN  && $logged=='Y')
{
echo "alreadyLogged"; exit;
}
 elseif ($rehash==$dboPW && $user_name == $dboUN  && $logged=='N')
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the php problem,it occur an error and return the error message. if ajax_login.php does not return "yes" or "no" it will show the second message, whatever it returns.

Answer (score 0):

Just need modify your PHP. try this :

> //Log In credentials
>
> // check if post if (isset($_POST)) {
>       // must initially to use check if on loggin
>       session_start();
>
> ```
> // set variable post
> $username = $_POST['user_name'];
> $password = $_POST['password']; // change if use sha1 or md5
> $rand = $_POST['rand'];
>
> // check query database
> $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
> $user = mysql_fetch_array($query);
> $row = mysql_num_rows($query);
>
> if ($row > 0) {
>     if ($user['LOGGED'] == 'Y') {
>         echo "yes";
>         $_SESSION['login'] = $username;
>         $_SESSION['password'] = $rehash;
>         $loggedUpdate = mysql_query("UPDATE Users SET LOGGED='Y' WHERE username='$user_name'");
>         exit;
>     } elseif ($user['LOGGED'] == 'N') { // you can use 'else'            
>         echo "alreadyLogged";
>         exit;
>     } 
> } else {
>     // invalid value password and username
>     echo "no";
>     exit;
> } }
> ```

Comment: Hi everyone, I tried the suggested PHP script and it still didn't work. I decided to run additional tests on the php file where I include a username and password in the script, then ran the script on its own. I wanted to make sure the correct echo statements get displayed. I tested all three possible scenarios and they all displayed correctly. 

Can it be the AJAX script that's causing the incorrect message to display?

Comment: are you have  tried change password use your encrypt? try testing ajax you can use firebug choose console tab.